# how to recognize a rub gesture on UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I m working with iOS 4 and working with UIGestureRecognizer .

my question is how can you create / detect a rub gesture on a table view cell . By rub gesture i mean how can i detect a right followed by a left swipe . i know how to detect left and right swipes individually and also on detecting it i know how to enable the editing for a single table view cell on which the swipe is made .. The main question is how to detect right swipe followed by left swipe or a left swipe followed by right swipe.

All ideas are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a very simple state machine to implement the sequence of swipes both ways.

Comment: could you be a bit more explainatory